# How to ignore some subroutine calls in NYTProf reporting

Tags: perl, profiling

I'm trying to profile a Perl script, but CORE::sleep gobble all the space (and time) of my report.

How can i tell NYTProf to ignore sleep calls ?

Assuming we have the following script :

```
sub BrandNewSubroutine {
  sleep 10;
  print "Odelay\n";
}
BrandNewSubroutine();
```

I want to get rid of the following line of the report :

- **Exclusive Time;Inclusive Time;Subroutine**
- **10.0s;10.0s;main::::CORE:sleepmain::CORE:sleep
  (opcode)**

Edit: Using DB::disable_profile() and DB::enable_profile() won't do the trick, as it add sleep time to BrandNewSubroutine Inclusive time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Outside of sleep, all the time goes into the print. You want to profile that? If you want to see how long the print takes, just do it 1000 times in an unrolled loop and time it. If it's printing to the console, it won't be fast. If to a file, it will be faster. If to a null device, faster yet. Do you have a real question here?

Comment: No. Perl's Benchmark module is made for such things. And I do not want to time a single print, but I want to profile a 7K lines perl script (and modules). sleep's time are a pain as they are oversized in comparison of the others function calls, and I want to get rid of it (in the report, not in the scripts).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest either wrapping the calls to `sleep` (possibly by use of method mentioned in [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions)) with `DB::disable_profile()` and `DB::enable_profile()` calls ([RUN-TIME CONTROL OF PROFILING in NYTProf documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.05/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm#RUN-TIME_CONTROL_OF_PROFILING)), or post processing the report to remove the offending calls.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sadly, using DB::disable_profile and DB::enable_profile does not exactly what I am looking for, as the sleep time is still counted in the report (see edit).

Comment: But, I'm interested in the second part of your answer (post processing the report to remove the offending calls). Could you please developp ?

Comment: @OMG_peanuts: I think you should be able to use [nytprofmerge](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TIMB/Devel-NYTProf-4.05/bin/nytprofmerge) as a base to work from

Answer (score 0):

CORE::accept is already ignored in the way you'd like CORE::sleep to be, so the mechanism is already in place. See this code in NYTProf.xs:

```
    /* XXX make configurable eg for wait(), and maybe even subs like FCGI::Accept
     * so perhaps use $hide_sub_calls->{$package}{$subname} to make it general.
     * Then the logic would have to move out of this block.
     */
    if (OP_ACCEPT == op_type)
        subr_entry->hide_subr_call_time = 1;
```

So with a little hacking (OP_SLEEP==op_type || OP_ACCEPT == op_type) you'd be able to ignore CORE::sleep in the same way.

I'd [accept a patch](https://github.com/timbunce/devel-nytprof/issues) to enable that as an option.